# Find the common values in columns in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the data frame of the style:

```
    animal   animal
A    Dog      Dog
B    Cat      Cat
C    Pig      Pig
D    Cat      Dog
```

The different entries in row D tell me there is an error. I need to remove all rows where the animals are not the same. The columns do have the same name.

I'm sure this should be simple!
Many thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you get a DataFrame with columns that are the same name? Can you force them to different? `df.columns = ['animal1', 'animal2']`.

Comment: Thanks - I inherited the dataframe.

Comment: Having checked the source. If anyone's interested the data was produced by: pd.concat([df1, df2], axis = 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preparatory code generates a dataframe with the same structure as yours. Interestingly, I was unable to name the columns `animal` and join with `suffix = ("","")` -- that throws an error `ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index([u'animal'], dtype='object')`. @chrisaycock's comment to rename the columns works just fine.

```
import pandas as pd

# prepare the dataframe
a1 = ['Dog','Cat','Pig','Cat']
a2 = ['Dog','Cat','Pig','Dog']
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"ani": a1})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"ani": a2})
# trickery required to get two columns with the same name
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True,right_index = True, suffixes=("mal", "mal"))

# fix the column names
df.columns = ['animal1', 'animal2']

# keep only matching rows
df = df[df.animal1 == df.animal2]
```

Answer (score -2):

Iterating through the data frame based on the index and checking for return value.

```
>>> for i in df.index:
...     if len(set(df.ix[i])) != 1:
...             df.drop(i)
```

Comment: Iterating over a DataFrame is extremely sub-optimal.