# Is it possible to find common values in two dataframes using Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df1 that is the list of e-mails of people that downloaded a certain e-book, and another dataframe df2 that is the e-mails of people that downloaded a different e-book.

I want to find the people that downloaded both e-books, or the common values between df1 and df2, using Python.

Is it possible to do that? How?

Comment: If you liked my answer, please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

This was already discussed. Can you click on the below link

[Find the common values in columns in Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30989298/find-the-common-values-in-columns-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the two data frames as `df1` and `df2` with `email` column, you can do the following:

```
intersected_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner')
```

This data frame will have the values corresponding to emails found in df1 `and` df2

Answer (score 1):

1. Dump the emails from `df1` into a set, in order to avoid duplicates.
2. Dump the emails from `df2` into a set, for the same reason.
3. Find the intersection of these two sets, as such:

````
set1 = set(df1.Emails)`
set2 = set(df2.Emails)
common = set1.intersection(set2)```
````

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should merge the two dataframes

```
merged = pd.merge(df1, df1, how='inner', on=['e-mails'])
```

and then drop the Nan values:

```
merged.dropna(inplace=True)
```